# Multiple UIViews in XIB of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinib

I've been trying to make a custom UITableViewCell with a UIScrollView.
I have a .xib which contains a UITableViewCell (that contains only a UIScrollView) and a UIView that is the content view for the cell's scrollView.

Alright, now here's the code for the UITableView that should display the custom cell :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RecessCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Recess"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        RecessCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Recess"];
        return cell;
}
```

The header for the RecessCell class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RecessCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@end
```

scrollView is an outlet for the UIScrollView inside each cell.
contentView is an outlet for the UIScrollView's content view.

Well, so far everything seems legit, but when I run the app:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key contentView.'

I've read plenty about that run-time error, all I could find is :

- I need to verify that the contentView is actually declared in
  the header. (as you can see, it is declared there)
- I need to change UITableViewCell to RecessCell in cellForRow, which I did.

How can I fix this problem? is creating custom UITableViewCells so difficult?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create another outlet called contentView in your header file. The UITableViewCell already has a property called contentView.

Also if you are creating a .xib with a UITableVieCell and you are adding views to the UITableViewCell the views will be added to the content view. 
So what you need is to go in your .xib file and remove the link between the view that is linked to your contentView IBOutlet. (You can also delete that view, but be careful so that you won't delete the subviews)

Comment: My xib has 2 ***root*** views: UITableCell that contains UIScrollView, and a UIView that I want to be the content of the scrollView. this view is not in the view hierarchy of the UITableCell because they are separated. What I've been trying to do is making the scrollView inside the custom UITableViewCell to present the other UIView from the same .xib. I've tried to change the property name, yet the same problem appears. How can I achieve what I was saying?

Comment: SO let me get this straight, you want UITableViewCell->UIScrolllView->UIView, but for that you have 2 roots view because ? (I don't want to be rude I just want to understand your problem)